Issues with JSON Deserialization and Console Input in a C# Console Application
I have a console application where I want to read commands from an input file and write the corresponding output to another file. One of my example commands looks like this:
[{"command":"addItem","payload":{"id":1,"catId":1,"sId":1,"price":1.2,"quantity":1}}]

I am trying to deserialize this command using System.Text.Json. Here is the relevant code snippet:
public class Input
{
    public string Command { get; set; }
    public object Payload { get; set; }
}

List<Input> command = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Input>>(commandLine);

I chose to use object for the Payload property because it can vary based on the command type. However, I am facing an issue where the deserialization always returns a null value during debugging.
Additionally, I am reading the input file with the following code:
string inputFilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "input.txt");

if (!File.Exists(inputFilePath))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Not found: {inputFilePath}");
    return;
}

 string jsonContent = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(inputFilePath);
 List<Input> commands = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Input>(jsonContent);

foreach (var commandLine in commands)
{
    await ExecuteCommand(commandLine);
}

I implemented this method to facilitate debugging, but I would also like to know how to read the input file path directly from the console instead.
Could someone help me with both deserialization issues and reading the input file path from the console?

The JSON you showed does not correspond to an object. It corresponds to an array containing one object.  I do not know why the Json Deserializer did not throw when you tried to deserialize an array as an object; it may be that it is one more of those contemptible pieces of nonsense that utilize silent failure.

thank you for your answers i edit my question based on your answer @MikeNakis and Daniel A. White

Now your Java isn't valid Java, either. So, you have not actually tried running the code that you are showing.  Please post an MRE.

FOr that I would suggest using dynamic type. To correctly handle deserialization, you'd need to use Newtonsoft nuget:
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var rawJson = @"[{""command"":""addItem"",""payload"":{""id"":1,""catId"":1,""sId"":1,""price"":1.2,""quantity"":1}}]";

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(rawJson);

Console.WriteLine(deserialized[0].command);
Console.WriteLine(deserialized[0].payload.id);
Console.WriteLine(deserialized[0].payload.catId);
Console.WriteLine(deserialized[0].payload.sId);
Console.WriteLine(deserialized[0].payload.price);
Console.WriteLine(deserialized[0].payload.quantity);

.NET fiddle

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonDeserializer
{
public class Input
{
    public string Command { get; set; }
    public dynamic Payload { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the path to the JSON file:");
        string filePath = Console.ReadLine();

        // Check if the file exists
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file path entered is invalid or the file does not exist.");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            // Read the file content
            string jsonContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

            // Deserialize the JSON into a list of Input objects
            List<Input> inputs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Input>>(jsonContent);

            // Output the results
            foreach (var input in inputs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Command: {input.Command}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Payload: {input.Payload}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while processing the file: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

}
The above solution worked for me, hope it helps you

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
